# Swift: UIScrollView not displaying child view controller using XLPagerTabStrip

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, xlpagertabstrip

I have been following the XLpagerTabStrip cocoapods extension to set up a tab bar at the top of my view controller (https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip).
I am implementing the ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController and have followed the steps exactly, but the UIScrollView is not displaying the child view controllers.

code within the tabbed view controller:

```
import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip

class MenuTabStrip: ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.settings.style.selectedBarHeight = 5.0
    self.settings.style.selectedBarBackgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()


    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewControllersForPagerTabStrip(pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController]{

    return [Reminders(), testbobViewController()]
}
```

example code within the child view controllers:

```
import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip

class testbobViewController: UIViewController, IndicatorInfoProvider {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


func indicatorInfoForPagerTabStrip(pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> IndicatorInfo {
    return IndicatorInfo(title: "test bob")
}
```

[Image showing the connections of the ButtonBarView and UIScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVCnW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should use storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier 
in the

```
    override func viewControllersForPagerTabStrip(pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController]{
```

}

instead of direct initialisation of the ViewController if you use storyboard and IB